# Can I keep the bonus of a Steam preorder while gifting the game?

Tags: steam

So, "FINAL FANTASY TYPE-0 HD"'s pre-order on Steam gives you a chocobo courier and  a moogle ward for Dota 2. A friend of mine wants the game but he doesn't play Dota, while I want the courier but not the game.

My question is: can I gift him the game and keep the bonus items (or the other way around), or are the items only applied for the account that activates the game?

Comment: Could you just have your friend gift back the items after he receives the game?

Comment: You mean through Dota 2? Would that work?

Comment: You'll have to watch out for the non-tradability period though.

Comment: I see. Is there a risk the items are non-tradeable?

Comment: @ataquino I don't think you'll have to go through the DotA application to be able to trade.  If it's anything like TF2 you can trade your in game items from your Steam inventory just like you would trade your game to your friend in the first place.

Comment: Items from games are always non-tradeable for quite a lengthy time. Mostly something about 2-6 months.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness I thought it was only 2 weeks?

Comment: @aytimothy In my experience, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but there are a few caveats:

Your friend will have to trade you the items via the in game trading system (this is synonymous with the Steam trading system). That being said, some items are trade-locked, meaning that they can only be traded after a certain date, or are complete trade-locked, meaning they can never be traded. Most pre-order items are trade-locked, but only for a period of time.

For example, I bought Empire: Total War about 2 years ago, which gave me a special hat and outfit for Team Fortress 2. Now, I can sell it on the market, or trade it to a friend, but previously I had to wait a month.

**Note**

Trade-locking is specific to items, and can be different per item (depending on when it was traded last, if it was part of a promotion, etc), so be careful about that.